# How To Model and Recreate This Practical Slime Effect

Tags: modeling, compositing-nodes, transparency

I've just dived into Blender over the last few weeks in order to gain some skills to solve a filmic problem. I of course did the Donut tutorial and really enjoyed the process.

Here's my question:

I want to build a photo real model of slime to composite over the practical slime used on a short film set as it is "underwhelming". I've attached a frame grab from the film. The camera tracks the slime trail from the doorway, this is close to the end of the shot. I've tried to build models using metaballs and other shapes but I really can't seem to nail it. A see through organic shape that reflects light with air bubbles (particles?) could do it but I can't seem to get there. Might anyone point me in a direction..tutorial, etc that could be helpful. I've watched several like the Beer tutorial but can't seem to find an answer.

[image: slime to be replaced]
Several other questions come to mind.

If I am successful building something that looks good in Blender...

1. How does one export a finished detail rendered photoreal 3D model to import into Blackmagic Fusion?
2. Is there way to to fully render the model and bake in the transparency andshaders etc. in high detail in Blender?

I see models on line with glass textures etc. that look great that I have imported as FBX and they look like unshaded clay models. I outputted an FBX and quick comped into the scene, please disregard light and shadows..it's just for the detail and transparency. I know there are some fundamentals here that I am missing in the execution and workflow. Thanks for considering my project. Joe

[image: high quality glass w transparency in Blender...looks great]
[image: FBX from Blender comped in ..looks bad..no transparency, etc.]

Comment: Hi :). Could you please split this post into three separate questions? It'll make it easier to get answers :)